# Grape rails - get the uri from location where request has been sent from

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-grape

I have a [grape api](https://github.com/intridea/grape) + rails and a rails client. Now, in one of my API endpoints I need to get the uri (not ip) path to the client endpoint that send the request in order to determine my response on that, eg:

the client sends a request from http://example.com/send/to/api to http://myapi.com/my/api/endpoint.

So in my api endpoint I want to get the http://example.com/send/to/api, test for it and perform some actions when host is example.com

How can I get the requesting uri in my grape endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

After starting to write this question my friend suggested to add a `X-Request-Origin` header with the client uri as value when sending the request. Gems like Oauth2 allow you to [set headers](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/intridea/oauth2/OAuth2/Client#request-instance_method).

Then in the grape endpoints you can get the value using `request.headers["X-Request-Origin"]` which returns the client uri.

Just putting it here, hoping it would save others some time. =)